# How to play "mp4" videos in HTML5 player using PySid2 QtWebEngine?

Tags: python, html5-video, pyside2, qtwebengine

I'm unable to play the video (mp4) formats inside the QtWebEngine QtBrowser. I tried the same with mp3 files and withour any problem the music is playing. But When I use the same with Videos, the video is broken in the browser.
I'm using below code to display the html file.

```
    self.webEngineView.load(QUrl.fromLocalFile(initialUrl))
    self.webEngineView.page().titleChanged.connect(self.setWindowTitle)
    #I found the below global settings from stack overflow, even this tooo is not working
    webSettings = QWebEngineSettings.globalSettings()
    webSettings.setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings.PluginsEnabled, True)
    QtWebEngine.QtWebEngine.initialize()
```

Here is the HTMl code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
       <head>
           <meta charset="UTF-8">
           <title>Playing</title>
           <style>
               body{
                   margin: 0;
               }
           </style>
       </head>
       <body>
           <video width="100%" height="100%" controls>
               <source src="<filePath>.mp4" type="video/mp4">
               Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
           </video>
       </body>
    </html>
```

Where this same web page is opening with no problem in the normal web browsers...
Can Anyone help me with the code... Or Am I doing anything creepy?

Comment: what is the value of `<filePath>.mp4` and where is it located with respect to the .html?

Comment: In Linux it works for me correctly

Comment: It is a local path... and the same file is working in choome browser but not in qt browser

Comment: It seems that you have to compile a plugin: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebengine-features.html#audio-and-video-codecs